# How to create a copy of spreedsheet with a timetrigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I perform at midnight of each day the following events:

1. Make a copy of the main worksheet, the name of the sheet is the current date.
2. The copy spreadsheet should be locked
3. All the data from the main worksheet except from cell 1:infinite should be wiped

Comment: Try looking at `DriveApp file.makeCopy()` and the event object for time based triggers.  It's all in the documentation for apps script which you can find links to on this site.

Comment: "All the data from the main worksheet except from cell 1:infinite should be wiped
google-apps-script" Can you tell me more on what cell 1:infinite should cover on your sheet?

Comment: @DiegoSanchez 1:ABCDEFGH has simple text entries. I tried searching and did not find if it is possible to exclude cells from a wipe. It is also not the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a sample code you can try.** This should get you started.

```
function clearandcreate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ssId = 'spreadsheetId' // Sample : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetID}
  DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).makeCopy(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); // creates a copy of the spreadsheet (kudos to Cooper)
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent(); // clears all content from the 2nd row going down
}
```

**Use [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) like so.**

[image]

**References:**

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String)
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable